# Booting from an old internal HDD via USB without formatting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, usb, external-hard-drive

So I've been trying various methods over the past few months with no success. I have an old laptop hard drive from a spent laptop. The HDD is good and it contains a copy of some software which I cannot lose. I also cannot reinstall the software and apply the same license code on a new machine. I know I can open my new laptop up and swap out the internal drive for this one, but it's not ideal and I'd like to avoid this as much as possible.

My first step was to try booting directly from the HDD, I changed the boot options to boot from USB first and booted the drive using a USB Hard Drive caddy. It boots but when it gets to the windows loading screen it freezes and crashes.

I have tried creating an ISO image of the HDD but found I couldn't mount the ISO image correctly onto another spare HDD correctly and my laptop failed to even recognise the USB when booting.

I looked into hard drive transfer software but this is expensive and may not necessarily transfer licenses which is a bit pointless.

I have tried cloning the drive and booting. This works successfully and windows was able to boot; however when launching the software it asks for a license key. Reading up online some software notes the HDD serial number and this is most likely why it's asking for a license key.

My question is, is it possible to somehow boot windows from this HDD externally without losing the software installed or compromising the disk?

Many thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to call the software manufacturer and ask for a new license? I mean, it wouldn't be the first time someone's computer broke and he needed to reinstall. You *do* have a proper license for this software, right?

Comment: Here's the problem, I got a 1 year license which doesn't appear to have expired. It's from 2017. I do not know how I still have access to the software but I am most certain if I contact the manufacturer they will just remove the license.

Comment: So either the license is valid, and you should be able to transfer it to a different pc, or the license is *not* valid, and you should stop using it.

Comment: Thanks, are you able to answer my query?